# Get indices of equally rows from two different data.table's

Tags: r, data.table, query-optimization

I am trying to do something similar like here:

[R - indices of matching values of two data.tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896550/r-indices-of-matching-values-of-two-data-tables)

Here the original reproduceable example from the question above:

```
S.disc <- c(2000,2000)
S.max  <- c(6200,2300)
S.min  <- c(700,100)

Traces.num <- 3
Class.str <- lapply(1:2,function(x) seq(S.min[x],S.max[x],S.disc[x]))
Class.inf <- seq_len(Traces.num)
Actions <- data.table(expand.grid(Class.inf, Class.str[[2]], Class.str[[1]], Class.str[[2]], Class.str[[1]])[,c(5,4,1,3,2)])
setnames(Actions,c("k1","k2","i","l1","l2"))
States <- unique(Actions[,list(k1,k2,i)])
```

As an R beginner, I'm struggling to extend this example for all columns.

In my case, my first data.table has 60 columns and 2.2 million rows. The second data.table is a subset of the first one, i.e. it has the same number of columns = 60 but much fewer rows = 0.1 million.

In the end, I would like to have a vector with the length of data.table one = 2.2 million, with a TRUE value if the row exists equally somewhere in the data.table two, otherwise a FALSE.

I did a for loop, but it is highly inefficient and takes hours to complete:

```
S.disc <- c(2000,2000)
S.max  <- c(6200,2300)
S.min  <- c(700,100)

Traces.num <- 3
Class.str <- lapply(1:2,function(x) seq(S.min[x],S.max[x],S.disc[x]))
Class.inf <- seq_len(Traces.num)
Actions <- data.table(expand.grid(Class.inf, Class.str[[2]], Class.str[[1]], Class.str[[2]], Class.str[[1]])[,c(5,4,1,3,2)])
setnames(Actions,c("k1","k2","i","l1","l2"))
States <- as.data.table(sample_n(Actions, 10))


idx_filter <- rep(NA,dim(Actions)[1])

for (a in 1:dim(Actions)[1]){
  for (b in 1:nrow(States))
    if (sum(Actions[a,] == States[b,]) == ncol(Actions)) { idx_filter[a] <- T }
}

idx_filter[is.na(idx_filter)] <- F
```

How can I do the same with data.table efficiently?

Comment: Did you mean `b in 1:nrow(States)` instead of `b in 1:length(States)`? If you use `length` you have 5 `States`, with `nrow` you will have 10 (for 10 rows in `States`).

Comment: Yes, you're right! I meant nrow(States), many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`, you can first create a column `match` of `FALSE`. Then, you can join with `States` and set rows that match to `TRUE`. Then select the `match` column of logical values. Note that `setkeyv` will sort the `Actions` data table.

```
library(data.table)

setkeyv(setDT(Actions), names(Actions))
setkeyv(setDT(States), names(States))
Actions[ , match := FALSE][States, match := TRUE][ , match]
```

**Edit**: As noted by @chinsoon12, you can use `on = .NATURAL` and leave out `setkeyv` (just use setDT). I added `set.seed(123)` to make reproducible. It looks like the same result. Here is the complete code I am using:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

S.disc <- c(2000,2000)
S.max  <- c(6200,2300)
S.min  <- c(700,100)

Traces.num <- 3
Class.str <- lapply(1:2,function(x) seq(S.min[x],S.max[x],S.disc[x]))
Class.inf <- seq_len(Traces.num)
Actions <- data.table(expand.grid(Class.inf, Class.str[[2]], Class.str[[1]], Class.str[[2]], Class.str[[1]])[,c(5,4,1,3,2)])
setnames(Actions,c("k1","k2","i","l1","l2"))
States <- as.data.table(sample_n(Actions, 10))

idx_filter <- rep(NA,dim(Actions)[1])

for (a in 1:dim(Actions)[1]){
  for (b in 1:nrow(States))
    if (sum(Actions[a,] == States[b,]) == ncol(Actions)) { idx_filter[a] <- T }
}

idx_filter[is.na(idx_filter)] <- F

#setkeyv(setDT(Actions), names(Actions))
#setkeyv(setDT(States), names(States))

setDT(Actions)
setDT(States)

result <- Actions[ , match := FALSE][States, on=.NATURAL, match := TRUE][ , match]
result

  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [28] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [55] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [82] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

identical(result, idx_filter) 
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I just applied your approach, but when comparing the column "match" of data.table "Actions" with idx_filter, I don't get the same results: sum(idx_filter) == sum(Actions$match) -> FALSE

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm just facing another issue. Although sum(idx_filter) == sum(Actions$match) is giving me a TRUE, but sum(idx_filter == Actions$match) is NOT. This is important since the position is important for my intended task. I need exactly the same output as idx_filter, any chance to update your code? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my code (replaced length(States) with nrow(States)). I am comparing all columns. Table States is just a subset of the table Actions, and I would like to have a vector of length nrow(Actions) where a TRUE indicates that at this specific position the observation in table Actions exists somewhere in the table States. Please note, all rows in Actions are unique, thus also in States. Hence, if I have a TRUE value at position x in idx_filter, then I also need to have a TRUE at position x in Actions$match.

Comment: Your updated version works perfectly, a thousand thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With data.table >= 1.12.4, you can also use `on=.NATURAL` to join on intersecting columns (see item 10 in data.table_1.12.4 release in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/news/news.html).

Hence, another option is:

```
Actions[, idx_filter := FALSE][States, on=.NATURAL, idx_filter := TRUE]
```